# Jquery and twig, reload part of my page with updated twig variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig

I want to reload a part of my html page with twig in it using javascript. 
I use Symfony, so I send a variable into my html from my controller.
For example I have my html:

```html
<div id="block">
    <button id="reload">Reload</button>
    <p>{{ myVar }} </p>
</div>
```

My var could be equal to 1, and when I click the button I want to reload the page and increment myVar. Is that possible? I saw on google how to reload a page, but not how to update a twig variable. Thank for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are maintaining the state of variable in symfony and changing it according to user action so you need to tell the symfony controller that button has been clicked and its time to increment variable value

this can be done very easily

1) on button click make a AJAX request and route it to the function witch can increment variable and in return you can send redirect response

`return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('yourpage'));`

2) or you can also send a query parameter in redirect URL and check it in controller if value is true then increment the counter

`example.con?buttonClicked=true`

and in controller something like that

```
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $buttonClicked = $request->query->get('buttonClicked');
    if($buttonClicked) {
      clicked++
    }

}
```

1st method is recommended