# Update part of page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, twig

I have a project where I can add elements and select them (it is a template creator).

- Here is how my page looks (so that you understand everything better), on the left there is all the different
  fields I can add.
- On the right is the inputs that are linked to the element I select (like its name, alignement, etc...)
- On the middle are the elements a can add, resize, and drag (and soon delete).

[image: template creator page]

Basically I've made everything work by creating a div of my list of inputs for each element I add, and by setting a `display: none` or `display: block` according on wether the element is selected or not.

This works but if I create a lot of elements, the page can be full of invisible divs, I am looking for a way to update the inputs via AJAX on 'element add' and 'element click'.

Also, I made this project with Symfony.
For now I have a `_inputs.html.twig` file where there is a div of all my inputs with and id that is specified when calling the view.

```
{% block body %}
<div id="inputs_{{ id }}" style="display: none;"><div class="form-floating p-2">
        <input id="{{ id }}_name" class="form-control bg-primary text-light">
        <label class="text-light">Nom</label>
    </div><hr><div class="form-floating p-2">
        <input id="{{ id }}_alignement" class="form-control bg-primary text-light">
        <label class="text-light">Alignement</label>
    </div><hr><div class="form-floating p-2">
        <input id="{{ id }}_font_size" class="form-control bg-primary text-light">
        <label class="text-light">Taille de police</label>
    </div><hr><div class="form-floating p-2">
        <input id="{{ id }}_bold" class="form-control bg-primary text-light">
        <label class="text-light">Gras</label>
    </div><hr><div class="form-floating p-2">
        <input id="{{ id }}_prefix" class="form-control bg-primary text-light">
        <label class="text-light">Préfixe</label>
    </div><hr><div class="form-floating p-2">
        <input id="{{ id }}_path" class="form-control bg-primary text-light">
        <label class="text-light">Chemin</label>
    </div><hr></div>
{% endblock %}
```

It basically is all my inputs with the id of the element (`{{ id }}`).

The thing is I've found a lot of different function, I know I need to call a function in the return of my Controller (which I will call from an AJAX request and my 'element click' and 'element add' events).

```
return $this->??????('render_inputs', [
        'id' => $id,
    ]);
```

Do I need to use renderBlock, renderView or anything else ?

I only need the right part of the page to update and I also need to store the values of the different inputs (when I select an element, type something in the inputs, I need to be able to retrieve what I typed).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43774602/jquery-and-twig-reload-part-of-my-page-with-updated-twig-variable) looks like something that would solve my problem from the title but the page gets refreshed (which doesn't work for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was actually very easy to solve, my understanding of how Ajax works was just too basic.

I simply needed to create a view (a twig file) containing what I needed to be refreshed and put it where I want.

On `myEvent` which triggers the update, you need :

```
$.get(
    'url/you/need/to/call',
    function(html) {
        $('#divWhereContentIsUpdated').html(html);
    },

);
```

Then create a new function in your controller which matches the `url/you/need/to/call` :

```
return $this->render('template/viewToAdd.html.twig', [
        'params' => $params // you maybe don't need to pass parameters, but can
    ]);
```

In your JS function, `html` is the content of the view you rendered in your controller. Then it is added to your page.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct you should be able to solve this with the function `renderBlock`.
The function `renderBlock` is situated in the class `Template`, so you would first need to load the template before you can use the function

```php
$template = $twig->load('template.html');
$template->renderBlock('render_inputs', [
    'id' => $id,
]);
```

---

Usually I place a container in my block, so I can easily update the HTML for said block, e.g.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" id="refresh">Refresh</button>
        {% block some_block_name %}
        <section id="some_block_name">
            Lorem ipsum
        </section>
        {% endblock %}
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $(document).on('click', '#refresh', function() {
                $.get('http://www.example.com/ajax/update.php', function(html) {
                    $('#some_block_name').html(html);
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what should I load (your `template.html`).
Like is it the template I need to update ?

Comment: You want to replace `template.html` with the actual template of which you only want to render a part/block from

Comment: Okay I understand.
So what I did in the end was call my `_inputs.html.twig`, put it in a variable `$inputs`. I'm now looking how to pass my `$inputs` to my render block

Comment: `renderBlock` accepts an array as params. How should I pass my entire view ?
And by the way thank you, I'm starting to understand how this works (the documentation really feels not natural..)

Comment: Yes, same as the regular `$twig->render(...)`, but the first parameter is the block's name

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think what I was asking was maybe not was I was really looking, I added an answer that fits my needs.